# Is there any way I can plot each of my for loops as a subplot?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, visualization

Probably a really stupid question but I am trying to condense my use of plots for my current project as it is currently producing a lot of them I will have to use as appendices for my thesis.

Below I've attached my current code which iterates through a list of dataframes to generate multiple plots using Matplotlib, however I would like to combine these into one image for the purpose of including with my research, rather than individual images. If you have any insight please let me know as this is stressing me a little!

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import figure
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
# import sklearn

# import map data
df1 = pd.read_csv('D:/Documents/Data Science/L4D2 Stats - No Mercy CSV files updated version/Normal/L4D2 Stats normal - c8m1 apartment.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('D:/Documents/Data Science/L4D2 Stats - No Mercy CSV files updated version/Adversarial/L4D2 Stats adversarial - c8m1 apartment.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('D:/Documents/Data Science/L4D2 Stats - No Mercy CSV files updated version/Helpful/L4D2 Stats helpful - c8m1 apartment.csv')
df4 = pd.read_csv('D:/Documents/Data Science/L4D2 Stats - No Mercy CSV files updated version/Neutral/L4D2 Stats neutral - c8m1 apartment.csv')
df5 = pd.read_csv('D:/Documents/Data Science/L4D2 Stats - No Mercy CSV files updated version/Random/L4D2 stats random - c8m1 apartment.csv')

df_list = [("c8m1 - Apartment Normal", df1), ("c8m1 - Apartment Adversarial", df2), ("c8m1 - Apartment Helpful", df3), ("c8m1 - Apartment Neutral", df4), ("c8m1 - Apartment Random", df5)]


for (title, df) in df_list:
    df = df
    df.describe()
    df.columns = ['Population', 'Special Spawns', 'Bot 1 Health', 'Bot 2 Health', 'Bot 3 Health', 'Bot 4 Health',
                  'Incaps', 'Bot 1 Intensity', 'Bot 2 Intensity', 'Bot 3 Intensity', 'Bot 4 Intensity']
    df['Special Spawns'] = df['Special Spawns'].fillna(0)
    df['Population'] = df['Population'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 1 Health'] = df['Bot 1 Health'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 2 Health'] = df['Bot 2 Health'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 3 Health'] = df['Bot 3 Health'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 4 Health'] = df['Bot 4 Health'].fillna(0)
    df['Incaps'] = df['Incaps'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 1 Intensity'] = df['Bot 1 Intensity'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 2 Intensity'] = df['Bot 2 Intensity'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 3 Intensity'] = df['Bot 3 Intensity'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 4 Intensity'] = df['Bot 4 Intensity'].fillna(0)

    # Normalise Direct and Indirect Involvement

    directsum_column = df["Population"] + df["Special Spawns"]
    df["Direct Involvement"] = directsum_column

    normalised_directsum_column = (directsum_column - directsum_column.mean()) / directsum_column.std()
    df["Normalised Direct Involvement"] = normalised_directsum_column

    indirectsum_column = df["Bot 1 Health"] + df["Bot 2 Health"] + df["Bot 3 Health"] + df["Bot 4 Health"] + df["Incaps"] + df["Bot 1 Intensity"] + df["Bot 2 Intensity"] + df["Bot 3 Intensity"] + df["Bot 4 Intensity"]
    df["Indirect Involvement"] = indirectsum_column

    normalised_indirectsum_column = (indirectsum_column - indirectsum_column.mean()) / indirectsum_column.std()
    df["Normalised Indirect Involvement"] = normalised_indirectsum_column

    # Compute percentage changes

    percentageChange = df.pct_change()
    percentageChange['Normalised Direct Involvement'].plot(label='Direct')
    percentageChange['Normalised Indirect Involvement'].plot(label='Indirect')
    plt.xlabel("Entries")
    plt.ylabel("Percentage Change")
    plt.title(title)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Create a plot with 5 panels arranged in 5 rows, 1 column:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5,1, figsize=(10,20)) #find an appropriate size 
for i, (title, df) in enumerate(df_list):
     ...
     percentageChange['Normalised Direct Involvement'].plot(ax=ax[i], label='Direct')
     percentageChange['Normalised Indirect Involvement'].plot(ax=ax[i], label='Indirect')
     ax[i].set_xlabel("Entries")
     ...
```